# How can I bind mount a directory with a space in it?

Tags: linux, mount

I have a drive mounted at /media/ that contains a directory with a space in the name - let's call it "My Stuff".

I would like to bind mount it to "My Stuff" in my home directory.  I tried the following in fstab, but all attempts to mount resulted in a syntax error:

```
/media/My\ Stuff /home/me/My\ Stuff none bind
"/media/My\ Stuff" "/home/me/My\ Stuff" none bind
"/media/My Stuff" "/home/me/My Stuff" none bind
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to replace every occurence of `space` within the directory path by `\040` in your fstab file.

So try :

```
/media/My\040Stuff /home/me/My\040Stuff none bind 0 0
```

Comment: You may need to first create the `/home/me/My\ Stuff` directory

Answer (score 0):

```
mount --bind /media/My\ Stuff /home/me/My\ Stuff
```

run the command as root user or prefix with `sudo`

Comment: I suspect the user knew that because of the examples they gave that didn't work, but wants a line that will function in fstab not just from the command-line.

Comment: Right.  I want this permanent.

Comment: Try:"/media/My Stuff" "/home/me/My Stuff" bind 0 0

or you may need the '\ ', but drop the none before bind