# Mount a folder with a space on Linux

Tags: linux, mount

I've been trying to get to some Access DB files (I know, didn't know this still existed either) from a Windows (7) machine onto my Linux Mint (19) machine.

Up 'til now, I've never had to mount something with a space in it, I've always done:

```
$ sudo mount - cifs //192.168.1.123/folder /mnt -o user=some,pass=user
```

but now I need to mount "Program Files" as it would seem the DB files are stored in the Common Data directory (for whatever reason).

I initially tried wrapping the mount target in quotes, which didn't work. I also tried adding a backslash before the space, again nothing.

After a quick Google's I came across this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/521334/how-can-i-bind-mount-a-directory-with-a-space-in-it/521338#521338) and changed my command to this:

```
$ sudo mount - cifs //192.168.1.123/Program\040Files /mnt/ -o user=some,pass=user
```

but this outputs:

> mount: bad usage
>   Try 'mount --help' for more information.

So it would seem I'm up against the wall on this one, how do I go about mounting a Windows directory that has a space in the name?

Comment: The `\040` syntax is for fstab, not for shell command line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This probably should be `sudo mount -t cifs ...`, note the `t`.

There are various ways to deal with spaces and special characters (see `man bash` for details), one way is to use single quotes:

```
sudo mount -t cifs '//192.168.1.123/Program Files' /mnt/ -o user=some,pass=user
```

Comment: I'd also add `-v` because of the extra information.

Comment: It is also uncommon to specify (`-o`) options after the positional arguments, so the device and mountpoint arguments should come last. `sudo mount -t cifs -o user=some “//192.168.1.123/Program Files“ /mnt`